# 10K-tools information oddities

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

The [10K-tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools) right-column shows some information regarding the review process:

[image]

1. Under *What is this?*, `\r\n` should be removed (is a clear bug).
2. The link to `chat` should end the sentence and require an ending period.

<sub>I am unable to view this on other sites (due to too low reputation), so I'm not sure whether this is a site- or network-wide bug. Otherwise I would have posted this on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).</sub>

Comment: This has been partly updated/fixed. #2 is still outstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, `\r\n` was fixed some time ago. And I just pushed a fix for the second issue.

Should be live in `rev 2014.3.13.1458`.